# How to give an icon to a .exe in SDL2/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, exe, sdl-2

### Problem :

I am trying to give an icon to my SDL2 application. SDL2 have a function named `SDL_SetWindowIcon()`, but the problem is the function only set the icon in the window app not in the .exe file this mean that when I pin it in my Taskbar, I see this:

[image: this icon]

### What I tried:

**SDL2 function**

```
SDL_Surface *iconSurface = IMG_Load("./src/Assets/img/Logo/icon.ico");
SDL_SetWindowIcon(window, iconSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(iconSurface);
```

**.rc file**

```
MAIN ICON "File"
```

### Important Details :

**Makefile Content :**

```
all:
    cls
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o TKM main.cpp src/include/manmade/Class/* src/include/manmade/Components/* src/include/manmade/Part/* -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
    ./TKM
```

**Coding Environment:**

```
OS : Windows
Text Editor : VScode 
Project build with a Makefile
```

Comment: An .rc file should be the solution. How do you compile and link it into the executable? What are the contents?

Comment: This is my Makefile( all:
 cls
 g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o TKM main.cpp src/include/manmade/Class/* src/include/manmade/Components/* src/include/manmade/Part/* -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
 ./TKM )

Comment: And in the .rc, I had tried this MAIN ICON "File" and MAINICON ICON "File"

Comment: Please edit this information into the question, don't leave it in the comments. I don't see the .rc file mentioned anywhere in the makefile, are you sure it's being used at all?

Comment: I do not know, how can I mentioned into the Makefile, like what is the code?

Comment: And I do not know if it is used. I had get the code for the  rc file in youtube and the people you make these video where using Code::blocks, that why I think the .rc is not working for me but I do not know what I need to add to make it works.

Comment: You need to build it with `windres` (I believe `windres -i my_file.rc -o my_file.o`), then add the resulting .o to the linker command (`g++ ...` in your case).

Comment: Also, obligatory reminder that you're misusing makefiles. A properly written makefile would rebuild only the source files that have been changed since the last build.

Comment: Ok, I have made it with windres but how I put the link into the Makefile to the ressources.o?

Comment: You just add the filename to that line of the makefile.

Comment: Ok thank you @HolyBlackCat, your thing worked.

Comment: You're welcome. This makes `SDL_SetWindowIcon` unnecessary too, I believe.

Comment: Yes, that true.

Comment: To mark a question as solved, select one of the answers and give it the checkmark. Don't edit the question. Since you self-answered there may be some lag on this; I don't know when you're allowed to award yourself the checkmark.

Comment: Hi @user4581301, thank for your advice and it is in two days that I can check.

Comment: Woo! That's longer than I expected. I figured a few hours, maybe a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Credits :

It is ***@HolyBlackCat*** you respond to this question in the comment. I am just putting it in the answer section with more details.

I add see some video and website to get knowledge in C++ and SDL2.

### Step 1

Create a `.rc` file.

### Step 2

Inside of the `.rc` file write this line of code:

```
MAIN ICON "./thePath/of/yourImage.ico"
```

### Step 3(for simple Makefile)

In the terminal launch this command:

```
windres -i yourRCFileName.rc -o yourRCFileName.o
```

### Step 4(for simple Makefile)

Put the path of your `.o` file(ex: yourRCFileName.o)
after main.cpp in the Makefile to assign your icon to the .exe file:

```
all:
    cls
    g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o test main.cpp yourRCFileName.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
    ./test
```

### Step 3(for big Makefile)

It is like when you make it with .cpp file. When you make change in your `.rc` file it will launch the command(@windress ...) otherwise nothing happen.

```
yourRCFileName.o: yourRCFileName.rc
    @windres -i $^ -o $@
```

### Step 4(for big Makefile)

You put the path of your `.o` file in the right section like always:

```
stackoverflowApp.exe: main.o yourRCFileName.o
    g++ -std=c++20 -I src/include -L src/lib $^ -o $@ -lmingw32 -otherLibraires
    ./stackoverflowApp
```

### Important Details :

The image need to be a `.ico` or you are going to get the following error message:

```
C:\mingw64\bin\windres.exe: icon file `./src/Assets/img/apple.png' does not contain icon data
```

### Tips :

You can use a website such as https://icoconvert.com/ to convert your image but they accept only these image :

```
PNG, JPG or BMP image( maximum size: 50 MB )
```

Comment: Instead of using sketchy websites, ImageMagick can do this conversion: `magick *.png result.ico` (or `convert *.png result.ico`, depending on the version).